# Object Oriented C++ Abstraction Architecture

Tags: c++, oop, architecture, callback, sdl

**Background Information**

I'm currently taking a computer graphics class. The way we're learning the main concepts is by making an abstraction that anyone could use (aka a simple 3D library). We're using SDL for the real graphics part. Actually, all we use SDL for is to render and manipulate a pixel buffer. We're only allowed to use that. But our abstraction is supposed to allow the client to draw pixels, lines, triangles, etc. all the way to complete models composed of those triangles.

Things were going along pretty smoothly... until the professor took a look at my abstraction. He said it wasn't very object oriented.

**My Question**

I'm not looking so much for a review of my code, as I'm looking for some general advice and suggestions on how to design this SDL library using sound Object Oriented principles.

**What I have so far**

My code actually makes good use of some object oriented principles. I have the following objects working fine so far:

- Vec4 - represents coordinates or colors. It does operations related to vectors.
- Mat4 - represents a 4x4 matrix that I use for transformations and such. Does operations related to matrices, such as multiply by another matrix, by a vec4, etc.
- MatrixFactory - creates different types of Mat4 (MatrixTranslate, MatrixRotate, etc)
- Shape - an interface used to make drawing various shapes easier

  - Dot : Shape
  - Line : Shape
  - Triangle : Shape

My "engine" itself does the following (based somewhat on the [three.js](http://aerotwist.com/lab/getting-started-with-three-js/) structure):

- Creates a window (the main window where things are drawn)
- Creates a scene (where shapes are displayed)
- Registers callback functions based on keyboard events (key presses)

**Where I'm struggling specifically**

The main thing I'm struggling with so far is handling callbacks. For instance, to draw a triangle, I currently do something like the following:

```
int main()
{
    // Create instance of my library
    RDL* rdl = new RDL(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 32); 


    // Draw a triangle when T is pressed
    // RDL_KEY_t = #define RDL_KEY_t SDLK_t for consistency 
    rdl->registerKeyEvent(RDL_KEY_t, drawTriangle);

    rdl->show();

    return 0;
}


// X, Y, Z and R, G, B are random values not shown for simplicity
void drawTriangle(RDL* rdl)
{
    RDL_Point p1(Vec4(X, Y, Z), Vec4(R, G, B));
    RDL_Point p2(Vec4(X, Y, Z), Vec4(R, G, B));
    RDL_Point p3(Vec4(X, Y, Z), Vec4(R, G, B));

    rdl->insertShape(RDL_Triangle(pt1, pt2, pt3));
}
```

Inside RDL::show() I run the standard SDL loop where I do 2 things:

- Call any registered callbacks
- Drawn shapes in my vector where all shapes are stored

But this is no good. If I insert 10 triangles, they all draw nicely. But if I want to rotate a specific one, I can't do that because my callbacks only give me access to my RDL object from main.

Any ideas, tips, or general advice?

Thank you very much. I know this is a long question...

Comment: This site is better suited: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also, why are you using `new`? This is C++, not Java.

Comment: Because operator new is how you construct objects in C++?

Comment: @brendanw it's how you try to avoid constructing objects in C++

Comment: Nah, `new` is really only for dynamic (a.k.a. heap) allocation. Still, intentional?

Comment: In this particular case, does it even matter?

Comment: @EqSum Given that your example code will never call the destructor of `RDL`, which could do something important (serializing state etc.): Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your callbacks are plain old functions. This is what's wrong with them. Imagine you can only have functions with no arguments. Or functions with one argument of a fixrmed type. You would not go too far with that. But your callbacks are just like that.

You want to be able to pass a function **and** its arguments to your `RegisterXyzEvent()`. When the time comes, your framework should call the function with supplied arguments.

A function bundled with (some of) its arguments is called in C++-speak a "bound function" or a "function object" or sometimes a "functor" (the last one is a very wrong name that unfortunately stuck). You need to learn how these bound functions work, how to build them, how to use ones that come with the standsrd library, and how to roll your own. Then make `RegisterXyzEvent()` accept such function objects, and make your framework call them.

Some keywords to search: function object, boost::bind, std::function.

Sorry about a brief answer with no examples. My phone keyboard is tiresome, and I think you are better off learning this stuff on your oelwn anyway.